# Le « sabre laser » : de quoi s'agit-il en fait et comment s'appelle-t-il ainsi ?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, figure-de-style, sport

> La Fédération française d'escrime adopte le sabre laser. (titre d'[article](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/insolite/201902/18/01-5215134-la-federation-francaise-descrime-adopte-le-sabre-laser.php) dans *La Presse*)

Sans blague :

> Le sabre définit l’objet d’où sort une ou plusieurs lames
>   énergétiques.
>
> Il comporte plusieurs parties : un émetteur, une poignée, un
>   activateur et un pommeau et éventuellement une garde.
>
> La lame définit le tube en polycarbonate éclairé par une LED qui va de
>   la sortie de l’émetteur du sabre jusqu’à l’extrémité de l’embout.
>
> L’embout est la partie en polycarbonate ou MMA situé à l’extrémité de
>   la lame. Il doit être rond.
>
> La poignée du sabre laser doit être composée d’un alliage métallique,
>   sans excroissance.
>
> Le sabre laser définit l’objet composé du sabre et de la lame. La
>   longueur totale du sabre laser est mesurée de l’extrémité du pommeau à
>   la pointe de la lame et doit être comprise entre 100 cm (inclus) à 110
>   cm (exclus).
>
> ---
>
> [ Extrait du [règlement national](https://www.comite-escrime95.com/app/download/10606116852/REGLEMENT_Livret1_Technique_v15112018.pdf?t=1545841625) pour les combats sportifs au
>   sabre laser de l'[Académie de Sabre Laser](https://www.comite-escrime95.com/acad%C3%A9mie-de-sabre-laser/), entité de la [Fédération
>   Française d'Escrime](http://www.escrime-ffe.fr/les-differentes-pratiques/la-federation-francaise-drescrime-deploie-son-concept-academie-de-sabre-laser) étant la seule organisation officielle ayant
>   compétence pour enseigner et organiser la pratique du sabre laser sur
>   le territoire conformément aux directives et missions du ministère des
>   sports. ]

- Quel est le terme technique (réel) qui désigne cet objet (le « sabre laser »<sup>1</sup>) ?
- Comment appelle-t-on la figure de style ou le procédé qui fait qu'on puisse l'appeler *sabre laser* ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Je suis parfaitement conscient du fait que ce soit une traduction du [*lightsaber*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lightsaber) : « Un pari ambitieux quand on connaît les différences fondamentales entre l’escrime traditionnelle et l’univers fantastique du sabre laser. » FFE, directement tiré du lien sous la deuxième citation ; « Maître Yoda, dépoussiérer son français, il le doit. » directement tiré de l'article de *La Presse* lié à la fin de la première citation. J'espère qu'on aura compris que le *sabre laser* n'existe pas et donc qu'il n'y a pas de [*laser*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8357770) ici : « Un sabre laser est une arme fictive de la saga cinématographique Star Wars. » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabre_laser)). Enfin je n'ai pas posé la question, qui se veut plus qu'un simple titre, sur [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13958/what-powers-a-lightsaber).</sub>

Comment: En tout cas, *ceci n'est pas une pipe...*

Comment: @jlliagre En effet, le terme ne convient pas, ni même _pipe laser_ ! ;-)

Comment: La question est parfaitement valide, l'information qui s'y trouve, véridique, et rien ne justifiait ces 4 votes négatifs, mais malheureusement il y a je crois un petit nombre de contributeurs de mauvaise foi, ignares, racistes et fachos qui agissent en vandales comme des clones en réunion. Pour la réflexion on repassera. Ils ignorent tout du fait français malgré leurs prétentions, ils sont imperméables au savoir, à l'éthique, au bon usage. Il n'ont vraiment rien à contribuer sauf la bêtise et l'incurie. C'est sans importance, ma question va rester, et les emmerder pour longtemps, à mon image !

Answer (score 4):

C'est juste l'expression officielle consacrée dès les premières traductions de la saga *Star Wars*, *La guerre des étoiles*, avec toutes les licenses artistiques que ce genre d'activité autorise.

On retrouve cette juxtaposition de noms dans d'autres expressions: *disque vinyle*, *bas nylon*, *stylo encre*, ...

**En réponse à l'affirmation que le sabre laser n'en est pas un:**

Je ne suis pas assez versé dans les sciences de la Force pour affirmer sans doute aucun qu'il ne s'agit pas de laser. Il est même possible que la lumière observée ne soit qu'un sous-produit de la véritable lame sous-jacente.

De toute façon, on peut affirmer qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un sabre. Le sabre est généralement courbe contrairement à l'épée. Il ne s'agit pas d'un fleuret ni d'un glaive qui sont des armes d'estoc et pas de taille, alors que le sabre laser convient aux deux situations. Discriminer sur le nombre de tranchants est assez difficile à la simple observation des combats.

J'opterais donc pour *épée à lame éclairante rétractable*.

(Par conséquent, la figure de style qui fait qu'on puisse l'appeler *sabre laser* s'appelle un *mensonge*, de la catégorie *marketing*)

Comment: En quoi « sabre laser » serait insatisfaisant en tant que terme technique? Pour la figure de style je convient que je n’ai pas répondu.

Comment: Parce qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un sabre laser ?

Answer (score 1):

> Sabre lumineux DEL/électronique de compétition (d'escrime).
>   Sabrolumière (inpiré de [*sabrolaser*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lightsaber#Translations)).
>  [Électroluminescente](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26533120) à
>   lumière déployée/dirigée en tube polycarbonate.
>  Manche/poignée à
>   [DEL](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2078405) encastrée pour [accessoire/adjonction/instrument terminal](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17497381)
>   d'escrime.
>  Système d'escrime émetteur-tube à DEL.
>  [Sabre
>   d'apparat](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=SABRE%20APPARAT) DEL.
>  Réplique de/faux « sabre laser » (DEL).

On parle du « sabre laser » par analogie ou [métaphore](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3203) avec le sabre laser (en science-fiction), voire par [hyperbole](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3212).